# error Additional information: No devices of the category

Tags: c#

I use DirectX.Capture and DShowNet dll in my project. I get video stream from a video device correctly on my laptop (Windows 8). I tried it on another laptop (Windows 8.1) and worked correctly too.

But I get an error when I execute it on my PC (Windows 8.1).

I install my video device driver true on PC and it works by it's manufacturer's software and shows video stream. But it doese not work with my code.

And I get below error on below line:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in DirectX.Capture.dll
>
> Additional information: No devices of the category

Here's my code:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    filters = new Filters(); // error is on this line

    if (filters.VideoInputDevices != null)
    {
        try
        {
            preview(deviceNumber);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Maybe any other software is already using your  WebCam.\n\n Error Message: \n\n" + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would be worth checking the `dxdiag` info, and checking if there are any differences between the two 8.1 machines.

Comment: i checked. my PC has strong hardware. it support cpu corei7 .but two laptop are corei3. the reason might be this? so it's very bad .

Comment: Do this 1) connect the capture device 2) run dxdiag 3) click "save all information" 4) save it to a text file 5) post it somewhere we can read it. Repeat the above steps from both the machine that works, and the one that doesnt (make sure you clearly indicate which one is which).

Comment: excuse me. here : http://www.4shared.com/office/fsqJPkPIba/DoseNotWork.html
http://www.4shared.com/office/ePkd8grNba/Work.html

Comment: cant download from those links.. you might want to try pastebin.

Comment: i put here :http://www.uplooder.net/cgi-bin/dl.cgi?key=ed5c40e89dad13c9fc24f40bd5ced761
http://www.uplooder.net/cgi-bin/dl.cgi?key=b3b140c93ef0038583a04e21fd53e138

Comment: i changed my platform to x86 and x64 and AnyCpu but it did not change

Comment: Your dxdiag files show that on the working laptop you have 2 capture devices, and the main device is the built-in webcam. Are you sure you are selecting the dinoeye (device 2) on the laptop that works, and not just using the (default) built-in cam?

Comment: yes i'm sure . i tried two webcam .laptop's web cam and Dino works correctly .i get video stream from laptop's webcam . and from dino too.

Answer (score 1):

It's been over a year, but I had same problem. In my case I've found out that the error originates in Filters.cs at this point

```
public FilterCollection AudioInputDevices = new FilterCollection( FilterCategory.AudioInputDevice );
```

That was because I din't have any microphone connected (audio input device), event though the program doesn't use it, as it only streams video. Once connected one now it works properly. Hope it helps.